# How can i plot direction fields in "Mathematica"?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I'm new to mathematica and i'm trying to learn how to use it, i was trying to plot a direction field but i couldn't, here are my differential equations:

```
y' = exp(-x) + y

y' = (1/6)y^3 - y - (1/3)t^2
```

and here is an example of one of the tries that i made :

`f[x_, y_] := e^x + y`

`sol = DSolve[y'[x] == f[x, y[x]], y, x]`

```
Table[StreamPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, f[x, y]}], {f[x, y], {None}}]`
```

Although i have no idea what this code means (in mathematica language) but i managed to gather it from some examples and some answers on the web and from this site. This code seems to work for some functions, such as :

```
 f[x_, y_] := y
```

or other simple ones, but does not work for functions containing exponentials or trigonometric (not always anyway - no idea why !)
i want to plot the direction field of the function that i provided and others, but i couldn't understand very well the examples in the documentations centre.
please help me with this, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Next time could you please look up correct syntax for all parts of your program. For example, exponential is not "e". You also do not need Table there. Corrected

```
f[x_, y_] := Exp[x] + y;
StreamPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image]